# NetworkOnMainThreadException with Retrofit and Rxandroid in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-android

This question has asked many times but none of the solutions is working. I don't know what's going on with code. Always shows `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Below code is my `ViewModel` class

```
class MainActicityViewModel(val context: MainActivity) : BaseObservable() {

val layoutManagerAppointment = LinearLayoutManager(context)
private val appClient = Appclient().getClient(context)
private val apiInterface = appClient.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
var rcyAdapter: RcyAdapter? = null

init {
    getList()
}

fun getList() {
    val observable = apiInterface.getUsers()
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // i have also registerd for Schedulers.newThread()

    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    observable.subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<ArrayList<Data>>() {
        override fun onComplete() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onComplete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onNext(t: ArrayList<Data>) {

            Log.e("SIZE", "" + t.size)
            Toast.makeText(context, "onNext", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.e("TAG ON ERROR", "" + e)


        }

    })
}
```

}

Below code is `Retrofit Client class`

```
class Appclient {

private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
private val baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

fun getClient(context: Context): Retrofit {
    //Here a logging interceptor is created
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor).build()

    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
    return (retrofit)!!
}}
```

And my retrofit interface

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/users")
fun getUsers(): Observable<ArrayList<Data>>}
```

Here is the `MainActivity` class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var vModel: MainActicityViewModel
var mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this@MainActivity, R.layout.activity_main)
    vModel = MainActicityViewModel(this@MainActivity)
    mainBinding!!.viewModel = vModel
}}
```

Comment: Where is your main thread, I mean your view class ?

Comment: Okay i update question with `view`

Comment: @AkshayPaliwal please check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
fun getList() {
    val observable:Observable<ArrayList<Data>>  = apiInterface.getUsers()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<ArrayList<Data>>() {
            override fun onComplete() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "onComplete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onNext(t: ArrayList<Data>) {

                Log.e("SIZE", "" + t.size)
                Toast.makeText(context, "onNext", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("TAG ON ERROR", "" + e)
            }
        })
    }
```

Observable needs to be chain calls when you do RxJava operations because Observable is not the builder pattern.

Comment: *Observable needs to be chain calls when you do RxJava operations* - where did you get that from? It's not true